# List<String> in java to List in javascript

Tags: javascript, java, html

I have a java code that I want to change to javascript to add script in my html file. The fundamentals of my java code is to print out list of API names

```
public List<String> getApiNames() throws IOException{
    String url = "https:give me api / // ";

    HttpClient httpClient = new HttpClient(5,10000);

    Response response = httpClient.callGetRequest(url, null, null); 

    String webPage = response.getResponseBody();

    ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper(); 
    mapper.configure(DeserializationFeature.FAIL_ON_UNKNOWN_PROPERTIES, false);
    Map<String, Api> apis = mapper.readValue(webPage, new TypeReference<HashMap<String, Api>>(){});
    List<String> list = new ArrayList<String>(apis.keySet());
    return list;
}
```

and I want to add to my html that is formatted like this,
[list format](https://i.stack.imgur.com/54Ih1.png)

Is there anyway I can add the java code I have to html file?

Comment: Based upon the image posted in your question, are you simply just wanting to view this data in your web page?  is the data already being retrieved in a servlet or other webs service?

Comment: Yes the data is already being retrieved. I want to show the list for the users to select the option

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In JavaScript, List<> is an array. Example ["one", "two", "three"]. List sizes do not have to defined up front in javascript and are dynamic. Below is an example using jquery's ajax to call a URL and get data from it:

http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/

```
function getAPIArray(callback) {
    var url = "https://someurl";
    $.ajax({
        type: 'GET',
        url: url,
        success: function (data) {
            //data will be the response from the server (the api's)
            // If it's not already in a list (array) then you have to build it up
            //Example:
            var array = [];
            for (var i = 0; i < data.results.length; i++) {
                array.push(data[i].apiName);
            }
            callback(array);
        },
        error: function (err) {
            alert('error!');
            console.log(err); //prints error object to console
        }

    });
}

function getsCalledWhenFinished(apiArray) {
    //do whatever you want with the data..
}

getAPIArray(getsCalledWhenFinished); //invokes the ajax call
```

Comment: thank you! so I would have to re-write the code in javascript... I thought there would be a way to implement my java code in my html file

Answer (score 0):

As per your further comments

`Yes the data is already being retrieved. I want to show the list for the users to select the option`

In you servlet you need to add the data to your request as an Attribute

```
request.setAttribute("tableData", data);
```

In your JSP you can use the `c:forEach` tag to display the data

```
<%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" prefix="c" %>
<c:forEach items="${tableData}" var="item">
    ${item}<br>  <!-- Or put in to option/select -->
</c:forEach>
```